# Using a variable to search an array instead of a static string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay, so what I have is basically three dynamic drop down boxes and a 2D array. I have each box adding their values together, and then I want the sum of the values to be searched for through the array to pull out the fifth value on whatever the row the value was on.

```
var shape = document.getElementById("shape").value;
var dimension_one = document.getElementById("dimension_One").value;
var x = 'x';
var dimension_two = document.getElementById("dimension_Two").value;
var selected_beam = shape + dimension_one + x + dimension_two; // combine all values from text boxes 
alert(selected_beam);

for (i = 0; i < array_shapes.length; i++)
{
    if (array_shapes[i][2] == selected_beam) {
        alert('Area=' + array_shapes[i][5]);
        //Area= array_shapes[i][5]);
    }
}
```

I know that selected _beam is giving me the value I want, and I also know that the array loop returns what I want out of the array but only if I replace

```
if (array_shapes[i][2] == selected_beam)
```

with

```
if (array_shapes[i][2] == "value I want to search for")
```

So what I really need to know is - why will it only accept it as a string and not as my selected_beam variable.

Comment: What does array_shapes look like?

Comment: array_shapes is being parsed in from a CSV file that is stored in a text box on the page. It is parsed into an array of arrays. The only way I can really view it is through firebug.

Comment: Can you post what the values in that array are? And can you post values you are generating in your alert(selected_beam)?

Comment: @MikeBrant The array is quite large and there are probably over a thousand values. Here are two lines from the whole though.

W44X335,W44X335,F,335,98.3,44,0,0,16,0,0,1.02,1.77,0,0,0,2.56,2.62
W1100X499,W1100X499,4.89,63400,1118,0,0,405,0,0,25.9,45,0,0,0,64.9,6

Comment: You need to use an uppercase 'X' for var x = 'X';

Comment: Thanks Mike! That actually did the trick!

Comment: Then you should accept my answer below. Glad to help. Funny that this just happened to be something related to my past life as a structural engineer, so it made sense to me what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your array values, it looks like you need var x to be uppercase like:

```
var x = 'X';
```

If I am reading your array correctly, it also looks like the beam size is in element 0 and 1 of the array not 1 and 2, so you may need to not look for array_shapes[i][2], but rather array_shapes[i][0] or array_shapes[i][1]

The first item in the array is at index value = 0.

Comment: +1 but sad that the asker failed to provide the most important thing in their question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some debugging.

To start off, you need to know why `selected_beam` !== **"your value"**.

I suggest you use this function to compare the strings:

```
function compare( s1, s2 ){
  alert("s1: " + s1.toString());
  alert("s2: " + s2.toString());
  if (s1.toString() == s2.toString())
    return alert("true");
  return alert("false");
}

>>> compare(selected_beam,"your value");
```

The problem might be as simple as having unnecessary characters in your `selected_beam`.

So where you have `alert(selected_beam)`, try to compare the strings and see if it returns true or false.

Answer (score -1):

You are concatenating values that you're parsing from a text box. The result will be a string

Try doing:

```
var selected_beam = parseInt(shape) + parseInt(dimension_one) + parseInt(x) + parseInt(dimension_two);
```

Comment: parseInt(x) will return a NaN.

Comment: I think he wants it to be a string.  My guess is he is trying to match names of steel beam sizes which are like 'W10x30' (from my structural engineering days).

Comment: That is exactly what i am trying to do. I want to match the beam sizes and then pull out info relating to them.